# How to include files from another folder?

Tags: php, directory, include, warnings, directory-structure

I don't really know how to describe my problem, so maybe I will present it graphically.

I've got folders of my site like:

***1. Project folder***

****a.** folder "components"**

- head.inc.php
- navbar.inc.php - there is php `include_once('class/functions.php');`
- content.inc.php
- footer.inc.php

****b.** folder "class"**

- dbconfig.php
- functions.php there is php `include_once('dbconfig.php');`

**c. folder (which i want to create) called "tutorials"**

- tutorial.php where is on header:

> ```
>  include('../components/head.inc.php'); 
>     include('../components/navbar.inc.php');
> ```

also in **main project** folder got files like

- index.php - where included all *.inc.php from folder "components"
- and some other files .php

I have no idea because I want to create a folder called "tutorials" and create a file called "tutorial.php" and include components from main project folder (i mean head.inc.php, navbar.inc.php etc.)
The problem is when i put "include" of this components, it shows me error like

> "Warning: include(components/head.inc.php): failed to open stream: No
> such file or directory "

Answer (score 0):

### How to Include?

```
<?php
include "components/head.inc.php";
?>
```

---

### Include Not working

Sometimes in php include_once won't work but include will, So try require / require_once / include / include_one

```
<?php
include "components/head.inc.php";
include_once "components/head.inc.php";
require "components/head.inc.php";
require_once "components/head.inc.php";
?>
```

> It's not like This is the only way to check, but if you see include_once helped you go do some research

---

### None of this is working

When going into the console tab of chrome / firefox / edge / brave and ... You can see a URL when you click on it it shows you an 404 Page so check the url and if needed you need to go back a directory like so:

```
URL : mywebsite.com/main.php/users/file/profile.php
The url we want : mywebsite.com/main.php/users/profile.php
```

**How we include it**

```
<?php
include "../profile.php";
or 
incude "../../ to go back two directories";
```

?>